# Tomcat deploy to remote server with war file as url

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat

Im trying to deploy a war file to Tomcat. I want to be able to do this via a webpage that lists my war files and then flings a file I click on to the Tomcat server and deploy it.

According to the docs found [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Deploy_A_New_Application_Remotely) I should be able to do this...

```
http://localhost:8080/manager/deploy?path=/footoo&war=file:/path/to/foo
```

where path=/footoo is the path on my server that I want to deploy to but can file be the URL??
I cant seem to get it to work.

sidenote: I can do this manually by using the tomcat manager websevice but this point of my project is that you can access my website from anywhere and deploy without having to access the server directly.

**EDIT**
I dont think I have asked this question very well so I am voting to delete it

Answer (score 3):

If  you read the documentation it says:

> Upload the web application archive (WAR) file that is specified as the
>   request data in this HTTP PUT request, install it into the appBase
>   directory of our corresponding virtual host, and start , using the
>   directory name or the war file name without the .war extension as the
>   path.

So, what you need is a PUT request.

`curl` can do that for you:

```
curl --user script:script --upload-file /tmp/test.war http://localhost:8080/manager/deploy?path=/tester
```

This logs you in as user `script` with a password of `script`, and uploads the `/tmp/test.war` file. When it gets to Tomcat, it will put it in the `tester.war` file, and deploy it as `/tester`.

If you want to do this through an actual web interface, the manager app will do that as well. You can select a war to deploy from your browser.

What Tomcat will NOT do is PULL the file for you given a URL. You need to PUSH the file up to the server.

Comment: when we deploy a war file to a remote server, should we change the localhost part to the corresponding ip . For eg for this java webservice should i change local host part to the corresponding ip             
 public class Users {
 public String insertData(String userName,String userPassword){
   try{
 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/login","root","chathura");
   PreparedStatement statement =  con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO users(name,password) VALUES ('"+userName+"','"+userPassword+"');");

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that feature exist. But you can build a system that uploads the war into the tomcat host and invoke the manager deploy URL